# PHP Web Service request not being received

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm fairly new to Web Services in PHP, but I've not run into this before.  I'm working with another company, who needs to receive a one-way web service request to their SAP system, when they hit our own web service. I've previously never had any problems formatting a string to an XML, and sending it in a request successfully.  However, no matter what I've tried, this company is saying that they aren't receiving my requests.  I'm not sure if there's something more complicated that I need to do, or some compatability issue that I'm not catching here.

Details:

My Web Service:

- Request/Response type
- RPC

Theirs:

- One-Way
- Document/Literal

The Request:

```
$Client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("exceptions"=>0, "trace"=>1, "username"=>'user', "password"=>'pass')); 
$soapXML = new SoapVar($stringXml, XSD_ANYXML); // $XML being the string that contains the XML
$Client->Request($soapXML); //Operation is void, no need to return to a var
```

If there's anything that I'm missing here with the request, please any help at all would be greatly appreciated.  Been pulling my hair out over this for the past two weeks.

Comment: What happens if you dump this: `var_dump($client->__getFunctions());`

Comment: `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(40) "void Request(Orders $Orders)"
}`

Comment: And what does `$xml` contain?

Comment: It contains the string that makes up the XML that I'm using to input.  Too long to post in a comment.  I then use that to create a SoapVar, reading it as an XML.  The uppercase "XML" is named differently in code, but its revealing =P  I should probably name things more appropriately here.